# How to find a user on Amazon AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is a user that can log in via FTP on a setup I’m working with. I can’t get a hold of the people who set it up, but it is with Amazon. I wanted to find out how I could see what permissions this FTP user has and how to set up another one for third-party access. I think it may be setup with EC2, but I’m not sure.

Comment: Is the Amazon EC2 instance on your own (or your company's) AWS account, or is the instance owned by someone else? If it is someone else, you will need to talk with them about gaining access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP server, if it is running on EC2, has no relationship with your AWS console - it is specific to your instance, and whatever ftp software is running on the server.

You will need to get access to the instance to find out any more information.  You can see the key associated with the instance from the console.  If you don't have access to that instance, there are ways to get access, but it will involve stopping the instance, mounting the volume to another instance, adding a new key to volume, and then restarting and using that key key to access it.